# Manipulate text-document.write

Tags: text, document, document.write

Is there a way to manipulate text in document.write code? I'm currently doing this

```
 if (score > 35) {document.write(output); document.write('<img src="images/Rabbit.jpg">')}
```

to print the output of the users choices, but you get a huge image and this tiny little text. Can someone at least point me to some information on how to, or (if even possible) the code to edit it in CSS?

Forgot to add that (output) outputs predefined text. That would probably help

Answer (score 0):

Just add this inline CSS to the image tag:

```
<img src="images/Rabbit.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
```

If you can't change the HTML outputted then add this internal CSS in your HTML head.

```
<head>
    <style>img { width: 200px, height: 200px; } </style>
</head>
```

Comment: I would prefer to change the text, forgot to add that (output) outputs pre-defined text based on the score.

Comment: @TheShadowGamer I've edited my answer. Hope it helps.